# Grid with round corners

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, cornerradius, wpf-grid

Is there a better option to make a grid with rounded corners? 
Might this cause any problems?

(Example: Wanted is a corner-radius of 10 & background colour of #FF292A2E)

```xml
<Grid Height="300" Width="150" Background="Transparent"  >
                <Border x:Name="roundBorder" BorderThickness="0" CornerRadius="10" Background="#FF292A2E"/>

</Grid>
```

Comment: Define "better"? You could have `Grid` inside `Border` too. Problems? In wpf? Nah..

Comment: "Might this cause any problems?" - yes. child elements positioned in corners will overlap and hide those round corners: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQJaS.png

Comment: For clarification, do you want ALL your grids in your WPF application to always be rounded corner radius?  If so, you will be better off to declare your own grid control template / style so they are assigned globally to your app.  Please confirm

Answer (score 1):

I imagine you more want the grid inside the border:

```
<Border x:Name="roundBorder" BorderThickness="0" CornerRadius="10" Background="#FF292A2E">
    <Grid Height="300" Width="150" Background="Transparent"  >


    </Grid>
</Border>
```

The `Grid` is just a means of laying out controls, so you first create `Border` with rounded corners and then add a `Grid` to this `Border` to which you can now add other things.